# Как добавить в массив конкретную часть другого массива JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Разрабатываю экран, где концепция похожа на выбор любимых исполнителей при регистрации на музыкальных площадках.
У меня есть 2 массива (будет больше), мне нужно в первый (главный) массив вставить часть второго массива. Не весь, а конкретную часть, например, мне нужны name-ы, где index<13.

Подскажите, плиз, как реализовать?

```
data() {
  
  return {
    cards: [
      { ownscoring: '1', name: "Хотел бы делать людей здоровыми, чтобы учучшить качество жизни" },
      { ownscoring: '2', name: "Хотел бы создавать новые технлогии, которые решают проблемы людей" },
      { ownscoring: '3', name: "Хотел бы работать с людьми на публике, чтобы делать мир ярче" },
    ],
    cardsdeep: [
      {index: '11', name: "Углубление 1", ownscoring: '1'},
      {index: '12', name: "Углубление 2", ownscoring: '1'},
      {index: '13', name: "Углубление 3", ownscoring: '1'},
    ],
    
    selected: [],
  };
}, 
methods: {
  
  addCards(card) {
    
    if (!this.isSelected (card)) {
        if (card.ownscoring === '1') {
            
            this.selected.push(card);
            this.cards.push.apply(this.cards, this.cardsdeep[this.index='11']

                // ...[
                // { name: "Хочу есть чиспы", ownscoring: '11' },
                // { name: "Хочу есть чиспы", ownscoring: '12' },
                // { name: "Хочу есть чиспы", ownscoring: '13' },
                // ]
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCards(arrayCard,index) {
   return  JSON.stringify(arrayCard).math(`{"ownscoring":"${index}"[.]*?}`) || [];
} 
   rootArray = rootArray.concat(getCards(cards,1))
```

Необходимо нормализовать выражение в соответствии со структурой вашего массива.